# Нужна дли запятая после "запросы"?

Tags: причастный-оборот

Вы сами формируете окончательную стоимость продвижения, выбирая запросы по которым хотите быть в ТОПе.

Answer (score 4):

Нужна. "По которым хотите быть в топе" -- придаточное.